# Magento duplicate on subdomain

Tags: admin, login, session, magento-1.4

For test and development, I duplicated our Magento shop to a sub-domain. Everything works, but not the admin Login. On the login page we get it. After entering my user name and password we don't log in. A new login Page is coming from our main site, so NOT the sub-domain. what can I do?

Thanks from germany

Alex

Comment: Which version of magento are u using ? Have you changed all the base URLs properly ? Do: select * from core_config_data where path like "%web/unsecure/base_url%"

Comment: Yes we have changed the URLs in DB. The site is working! Just this login problems... We are using 1.4.

Comment: Did you remove all cache files in var/cache and var/sessions? If using an opcode cache like APC/Zend, make sure you flush that or restart php-fpm or Apache for mod_php.

Comment: Check if you have a separate URL for admin. It can be found in System > Configuration > Advanced > Admin (for enterprise)

Answer (score 2):

Double check your .htaccess filer at root folder, does it have any rewrite rule,  we were facing problem with another magento setup inside subdirectory of root directory and every one and then the live site and dev site tends to not work, and after clearing cache it would work again...I would suggest not to keep your development enviorment on same server because with Magento it is always complex due to the caching mechanism...we finally  move our development server to another one and never had any problem since then...